# Rxjs - map equivalent of `withLatestFrom`

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, ngrx

### Issue

Is there a map equivalent of `withLatestFrom`, similar as `mergeMap` can be for `map` ?

(Questions like this have been asked around, but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer besides the one I show below with `map`.)

### Why?

To shorten:

```js
source.pipe(
  mergeMap((params) => 
    fetchExternalSource(params).pipe(
      map(response => [ params, response ])
    )
  )
).subscribe(console.info);
// Output: [ params, response ]
```

Into:

```js
source.pipe(
  mergeLatest((params) => fetchExternalSource(params))
).subscribe(console.info);
// Output: [ params, response ]
```

This is similar to behaviour of `withLatestFrom` and saves a lot of nesting and code duplication.

I may be missing something very obvious, but after crawling through rxjs docs for a few hours I just couldn't find the right match - will be very grateful for help!

Comment: Why not make your own operator that encapsulates this behavior? Check out https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#build-your-own-operators-easily and https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/operator-creation.md

Comment: Yes, it's very easy to write, but not that easy to type properly - that's why I was wondering if Rxjs maybe has something built-in.